# How to prevent string builder in log message if log level is disabled

Tags: java, performance, logging

When I have a log message in the code (say `logger.debug("Some message {}", someFunction());`) in situations where the log level is above debug, I've now built a string and called `someFunction()` for no reason. I'm used to C++ and there I would use some macro which would check the log level before actually calling `logger.debug(...)`, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent solution in Java. I'm looking for ideas to prevent filling my code with:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Some message {}", someFunction());
}
```

for every single log message.
Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: What Java logging package are you using?

Comment: Just for the record: if the performance hit from that method calls is really that severe to you, are you sure you want to do things that way in the first place? And beyond that: you have measured the effects of calling that function, you aren't **assuming** that you have a performance problem, you know and measured it?!

Comment: @KevinO We're using slf4j

Answer (score 4):

From Log4j 2.4, you can use `logger.debug("Some message {}", () -> someFunction());`. This will be lazily evaluated and the method `someFuction()` will be called only if log level is set to `DEBUG` or lower - see [this link](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-log4j-api-and-lambda-basics/).

Comment: This will work on most logging APIs (such as log4j and java.util.logging) but not with the current version of slf4j, which seems to be popular for some reason.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Sure? This answer here suggests something else? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284645/1531124

Comment: @GhostCat that's a different issue. slf4j simply allows "{}" (message format) to avoid doing string concatenation. It [doesn't help you avoid calling a CPU-intensive method whose result you pass in as a parameter](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-371). log4j and java.util.logging, on the other hand, allow the use of suppliers so your method is not called if not needed.